# The 3 polarizer filter experiment is shown with light. Does it work with radio waves?

Tags: electromagnetism

The classic experiment. First polarizer at 0 degrees, next at 45, next at 90 and light at 1/8 attenuation passes. Imagine you used metal gratings to polarize a source of non-polarized radio waves (say something in the UHF band) in the same manner. Would we expect the same result? Is there any reason to think that this effect is frequency dependent?

I thought I could try this experiment myself, but then I realized I don't know how to create non-polarized radio waves since antennas emit polarized radio waves.

Comment: Yes it works with radio waves. Or microwaves.

Comment: Just think of the transmitting antenna as the first of the three polarizers, and think of the receiving antenna as the third polarizer (a.k.a., the _analyzer._) Now, you only need one grating to serve as the middle polarizer.

Comment: unless it is from a star what RF wave coming from an antenna is not polarized? (not knowing the polarization is not unpolarized)